# (TLS with ECDSA certificates) handshake failed because of no shared cipher

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, ecdsa

I've been using a self generated RSA Certificate Authority to sign my servers certificates and so far everything worked fine.

Following the same schema, I'm trying to use ECDSA signatures, assmuming that smaller key size might make things easier for IOT devices.
Unfortunately I cannot get "working" certificates..

When testing the certificates with openssl (OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019) I get an error message (on the server) saying "tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher"

server side:

```
openssl s_server -accept 1443 -www -key ec_server_key.pem -cert ec_server_cert.pem 
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
140203753312320:error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:../ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:1419:
```

client side:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:1443 -CAfile ec_ca.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
139868026671168:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1618487596
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

everything works fine using RSA signatures

this is how I generate my certificates with RSA

```
#!/bin/bash
# CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY
# generate CA private key
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:password -out rsa_ca_key.pem 4096
# generate CA public key
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -passin pass:password -days 365 -subj "/C=CO/ST=State/L=City/O=Organization/CN=AuthorityName" -key rsa_ca_key.pem -out rsa_ca.pem

# FOR EACH SERVER
# generate server private key
openssl genrsa -out rsa_server_key.pem 4096
# generate server certificate
openssl req -new -sha256 -subj "/CN=server_name" -key rsa_server_key.pem -out rsa_server.csr
# generate extension
echo subjectAltName = DNS:server_domain,IP:10.10.10.20,IP:127.0.0.1 > extfile.cnf
# sign the server certificate
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in rsa_server.csr -CA rsa_ca.pem -CAkey rsa_ca_key.pem -CAcreateserial -out rsa_server_cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf -passin pass:password
# clean up
rm extfile.cnf rsa_server.csr
```

and this is how I generate my certificates with ECDSA

```
#!/bin/bash
# CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY
# generate CA private key
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -param_enc explicit | openssl ec -aes256 -passout pass:password -out ec_ca_key.pem
# generate CA public key
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -passin pass:password -days 365 -subj "/C=CO/ST=State/L=City/O=Organization/CN=AuthorityName" -key ec_ca_key.pem -out ec_ca.pem

# FOR EACH SERVER
# generate server private key
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out ec_server_key.pem
# generate server certificate
openssl req -new -sha256 -subj "/CN=server_name" -key ec_server_key.pem -out ec_server.csr
# generate extension
echo subjectAltName = DNS:server_domain,IP:10.10.10.20,IP:127.0.0.1 > extfile.cnf
# sign the server certificate
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in ec_server.csr -CA ec_ca.pem -CAkey ec_ca_key.pem -CAcreateserial -out ec_server_cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf -passin pass:password
# clean up
rm extfile.cnf ec_server.csr
```

Comment: Try using a different curve. The curve `secp256k1` is not in OpenSSL's default curves list. I'd suggest `secp256r1` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Changed the curve and everything is working now!

Comment: EC _signature_ is smaller than RSA but slower on client (especially if it's not one of the optimzed asm cases). The _cert could_ be smaller, but not using -param_enc explicit as you did, which also may not be interoperable; see (my) https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122686/how-to-use-openssl-ca-with-prime256v1/#220877 . (@Matt: I didn't notice we now recognize explicit params that match a named curve; fixed other answers.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I think that is in 3.0 only??

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the comment, that sounds good to me cause the client I'm using is a tiny device with memory constraints

Comment: This goes beyond the original question, but I indeed had interop issues, just in case you are interested. My setup looks like this: SERVER (debian vps): mqtt broker (mosquitto) behind a reverse proxy (nginx) that takes care of the TLS. CLIENT: iot device with mbedtls.

Comment: This is what I noticed: I generated the certificates (RSA and ECC) with openssl (as described in the original question) and tested TLS with openssl and mosquitto mqtt client on a linux machine: everything worked fine. However the iot client (mbedtls) was unable to connect (complaining about CN when using RSA and failing the handshake with ECC). I fixed it generating the certificates (RSA and ECC) using mbedtls utils. When testing the tls with openssl everything is still working fine.

Comment: quackmore: if you have time, you could try generating EC on OpenSSL _without_ -param_enc explicit; that _should_ be interoperable. No matter where you generate you need to put the hostname(s) in SAN if used and CN otherwise, but testing with `openssl s_client` _by default_ doesn't check hostname and thus won't report any error there; I don't know about mqtt client. @Matt: ec_curve_nid_from_params is in 1.1.0l (ell for Last?) and 1.1.1d+ releases, as noted in the answer I linked, and another on crypto; I didn't look in source-control.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for your time. It won't be soon, but I want to dig further about this. I'll report back.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I did regenerate the certificates without -param_enc explicit, and all the interop issues are fixed. I set up different scenarios and tested them with openssl utils, different browers, mbedtls clients and mqtt clients. Everything is working fine. Furthermore the EC certificates (using secp384r1) are 1/3 the size of RSA (4096) and I'm pretty happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the TLS version and dedicated curves in the both server and client side as showed in the following.

1. openssl s_server -accept 1443 -www -key ec_server_key.pem -cert ec_server_cert.pem -tls1_2 -curves secp256k1
2. openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:1443 -CAfile ec_ca.pem -tls1_2 -curves secp256k1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed this using a secp256r1 curve as suggested by Matt Caswell.